# Bootstrap 3 with blank space at the top above the navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just downloaded Bootstrap 3 Dist which contains only css/js/fonts.

I created index.html and pasted the [OffCanvas example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/), all works well so far.
I then changed the included navbar with the **Fixed Top Navbar** but now I see a 200px blank top space above the navbar that I cannot pinpoint using FireBug.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp9Rj.png)

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">

<title>Off Canvas Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 </div>

 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>


<div class="container">

  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
      </p>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/span-->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
  </footer>

</div><!--/.container-->



<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/offcanvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your CSS is externally referenced.. can you provide it please?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap's standard css files. You can find them on getbootstrap.com

Comment: thanks, checking now. Strange though as if its standard and non edited then there's no reason it shouldn't be identical!
Currently we can only see the working website, do you have yours hosted that you can link us to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add navbar-fixed-top to the navbar class:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
```